# How to auto generate slug in Django

Tags: python, html, django, slug

Trying to build a blog,
I need to auto-generate the slug for making the URL based on the article title.

*many thanks*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple way, i have explained  few simple and easy

you can add via admin.py

```
class ModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {"slug": ("your_field_name",)}

admin.site.register(Model, ModelAdmin)
```

you can use slugify on model save method

example

```
class Test(models.Model):
    q = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    s = models.SlugField(editable=False) # hide from admin

    def save(self):
        if not self.id:
            self.s = slugify(self.q)

        super(Test, self).save()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see the field auto populated within the admin form.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # This will be populating the slug field as you enter the title in the post form on admin site
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ['title', ]}
```

Outside of the admin site, just ensure to override the save method on the `post model`...

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

Class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.title:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

That should do the job effectively.

Comment: See the updated answer bro. Remove the `unique_for_date='publish'`